# How to visualize graph-like json

Tags: graph, graph-visualization

I have json files like the following

```
{
    "A": {
            "field1": "X",
            "field2": "Y",
            "next": ["B"]
    },
    "B": {
            "field1": "X",
            "field2": "Y",
            "next": ["C", "D"]
    },
    "C": {
            "field1": "X",
            "field2": "Y",
            "next": ["A"]
    },
    "D": {
            "field1": "X",
            "field2": "Y",
            "next": ["C", "E"]
    },
    "E": {
            "field1": "X",
            "field2": "Y",
            "next": ["C", "D"]
    }

}
```

Each key in the json is a node of a graph and in the `next` field are the connected nodes.

I'm searching for a simple solution for visualizing jsons like this.
In the example, edges are A -> B, B -> C, B -> D and so on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: read the json, convert to .dot format, then run graphviz to create the visualization.  https://graphviz.org/

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is

- Read the JSON file and store the links in a graph data structure
- Read the graph data structure, writing to the graphviz dot format text file
- Run the graphviz dot application to convert the dot format text file to a PMG graphics file
- Display the PNG file

This process applied to your sample file gives

[image]

Here is C++ code to read JSON file into the [PathFinder](https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder) graph theory engine

```
    // read  JSON into property tree
    boost::property_tree::ptree tree;
    read_json(myFile, tree);

    // loop over source nodes
    for (auto &src : tree)
    {
        // loop over destination nodes
        for (auto &dst : tree.get_child(src.first).get_child("next"))
        {
            // add link between source and destination
            myFinder.addLink(src.first, dst.second.data());
        }
    }
```

Here is C++ code to convert from the PathFinder graph structure to dot format text

```
        std::stringstream f;
        f << "graph G {\n";
        
        // loop over nodes
        for (auto n : nodes())
        {
            f << n.second.myName
              << " [ penwidth = 3.0 ];\n";
        }

        // loop over links
        for (auto &e : links())
        {
            f << node(e.first.first).myName << "->"
              << node(e.first.second).myName;
              << "\n";
        }

        f << "}\n";
        return f.str();
```